# Whether to add the chemical potential in the 2nd quantized Hamiltonian (Piers Coleman)

Tags: particle-physics, field-theory, fermions, many-body, ground-state

I am reading the Piers Coleman's book : Introduction to Many-body Physics. And I am now struggling with the construction of the 2nd quantized Hamiltonian. Typically I don't know whether to add the chemical potential part $\mu N$ or not.

In page 81-82 discussing the **fluid of non-interacting fermions**, he write down the Hamiltonian

$H = H_{S} - \mu N = \sum\limits_{\sigma}( E_{\bf k} - \mu )c^{\dagger}_{\bf k \sigma}c_{\bf k \sigma}$

and then state that the ground state is

$\left| {G} \right\rangle = \prod\limits_{|{\bf k}|<k_F,\sigma}^{} {c^{\dagger}_{\bf k \sigma}}\left| {0} \right\rangle $

To describe the excitation spectrum he then makes a particle-hole transformation. To my best of understanding, the excitation of the ground state can be obtained by adding a fermion with $|{\bf k}|>k_F$ or *extracting one fermion with $|{\bf k}|<k_F$*.

I am OK with the statement "adding a fermion with $|{\bf k}|>k_F$". But I am confused by the later statement *extracting one fermion with $|{\bf k}|<k_F$*.

**Here is my reasoning :**

To get some excitations, we need to find another state that has higher energy then the ground state. In this case, since the Hamiltonian is 
$H = H_{S} - \mu N = \sum\limits_{\sigma}( E_{\bf k} - \mu )c^{\dagger}_{\bf k \sigma}c_{\bf k \sigma}$
where the chemical potential $\mu$ is defined by $E_{\bf k \sigma} = \mu$. Therefore, to raise the energy, we can extract one fermion with $|{\bf k}|<k_F$ since a fermion with $|{\bf k}|<k_F$  will contribute $E_{\bf k \sigma} - \mu < 0$ in the total energy.

**However**, the above reasoning is based on the fact that we write the Hamiltonian as $H = H_{S} - \mu N = \sum\limits_{\sigma}( E_{\bf k} - \mu )c^{\dagger}_{\bf k \sigma}c_{\bf k \sigma}$.

If we, instead, write the Hamiltonian as 
$H = H_{S} = \sum\limits_{\sigma}( E_{\bf k} )c^{\dagger}_{\bf k \sigma}c_{\bf k \sigma}$, which is what he does in all the previous chapters, then we will not deduce that a excitation can be obtained by extracting a fermion with $|{\bf k}|<k_F$.

The examples for Hamiltonian without $\mu N$ can be found in the chapter 4.1 for Jordan-Wigner transformation and chaper 4.2 for the Hubbard model.

It seems that it is the form of the Hamiltonian that determines whether it is reasonable to use a particle-hole transformation to describe the excitation. And I can not understand why he add the $\mu N$ in chapter 4.3.1 for the fluid of non-interacting fermions.

Thanks for the reading. I would be extremely grateful for any suggestion! :)